# Selenium Python : get index of row of element found

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The URL is http://www.ukmi.nhs.uk/applications/ndo/record_view_open.asp?newDrugID=5073

I need to check if 'Evidence Based Evaluations' exists and if it does, print the contents under that. For finding the header, what I've done is :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentHolder']//td[text()='Evidence Based Evaluations']")
```

The full xpath for this is:

```
//*[@id="contentHolder"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[22]/td
```

The xpath of next element (which i need to print) is:

```
 //*[@id="contentHolder"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[23]/td[1]
```

I need to get the index of tr (22, in this case) so I can increment it and use that for the next step. However, the index of tr changes according to the ID passed in the URL. So how do I get this index?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are focusing too much on indexes and the positions of things within the DOM. This is the problem, not the fact you need to get the index of something but rather *you need a better way of finding those elements*.

Comment: Umm. Doesn't really matter now. I was able to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given xpath of 'Evidence Based Evaluations' is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentHolder']//td[text()='Evidence Based Evaluations']")
```

The xpaths of subsequent required elements are :

```
//*[@id="contentHolder"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[23]/td[1]
//*[@id="contentHolder"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[24]/td[1]
//*[@id="contentHolder"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[25]/td[1]
```

What I did was

```
inp = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentHolder']//td[text()='Evidence Based Evaluations']/following::tr/td[1]")
```

Then using

```
print (inp[i].text)
```

I was able to get the relevant data